# Simple Image Deconvolution issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

I'm working on some very simple image deconvolution for proof of concept.

The goal is to convolve an image with a kernel (I'm using a 5*5 gaussian matrix) and then deconvolve it in the fourier domain.

By taking the FFT of an both an image matrix and a filter kernel, element multiplying
them together, and taking the iFFT of the result, I am able to achieve the same result 
as a sliding kernel convolution. To undo this convolution, I should be able to element divide
the image's FFT and the filter's FFT.

However, when I try to implement this, I end up with a very strange texture thing. I know my methodology is right, but I cannot seem to find the bug in my code and it's driving me nuts.

```
# blur image
imblur = filters.convolve(im1, blurfilter)

# compute fft of kernel with padding
padfilfft = np.fft.fft2(blurfilter, s=im1.shape[:2], axes=(0,1))    

# take fft of image
imfft = np.fft.fft2(imblur)

# element division
deconvolveimfft = np.divide(imfft, padfilfft)
deconvolveim = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(deconvolveimfft))
```

Here's the output using plt.imshow():

[image: typical, problematic output]

And this is the original picture. I'm reading it in using `misc.imread` with flattening:
[image: cheering]

For what it's worth, `blurfilter` is defined as follows:
`blurfilter = (1./273.) * np.array([[1,4,7,4,1],[4,16,26,16,4],[7,26,41,26,7],[4,16,26,16,4],[1,4,7,4,1]])`

Comment: Won't some of those FFT results from the filter be at or near zero? What happens when you try to divide by them?

Comment: @MarkRansom very close to zero, definitely, but the result is just that crummy picture. I use `scipy.misc.bytescale()` to ensure the final output is the right range... without it values are much higher.

Comment: @paintedcones - Can we have access to the original image?  I'd like to play around with your code and see what's going on but I can't do that without the original image.

Comment: @rayryeng added image file. Hope it's accessible. I've tried multiple different images and I've also tried reading in image as float, float32, uint8, etc.

Comment: Great. I'll investigate while at work. Stay tuned!

Comment: Related - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26433/use-matlab-to-restore-the-signal-from-a-given-degraded-signal-using-tikhonov-reg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I actually was able to figure it out. Turns out it was an "issue" with my kernel. I found that, in general, a gaussian kernel with sigma > 1 will yield this strange noise issue. As @MarkRansom pointed out in the comments, the fft from the filter becomes very close to zero. For some reason, there is much less noise amplification when we use kernels with σ<1.